# Vue JS Disable Button aria-disable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make a button be disabled if there is a job running. I have the button state in the controller being passed to the view. The code works when the state is true but when it is false I get the following error -

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::orderBy('order_created', 'asc')->get();

        $buttonState = Sync::where('status', 'running')->exists();

        return view('orders.index', compact('orders', 'buttonState'));
    }
```

View

```
<sync-button :active="{{ $buttonState }}"></sync-button>
```

Vue JS

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:5px;" 
    :disabled="disabledComputedProp" :aria-disabled="disabledComputedProp" 
    @click="sync">Sync Orders</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['active'],
        computed: {
            disabledComputedProp() {
                return this.active ? true : false;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sync() {
                this.active = ! this.active;

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of the props 'active' is it `boolean` or `string`?

Comment: it is boolen type...$buttonState is true or false boolean

Comment: Try to direct the value of 'active' `props` to the attribute that you need to bind. I think no need to set it on computed property

Comment: Obviously you have syntax error. Check what HTML looks like and you will see the problem.

Comment: you pass array data to the component but you check as a object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using Laravel, Vue JS and boolean's. The boolean needs to be JSON encoded to pass to vue.

Changing the view to

```
<sync-button :active="{{ json_encode($buttonState) }}"></sync-button>
```

fixed the error.